# Backbone.js JSON Structure

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, data-structures

### I am confused on how to work with the JSON structure of an API with backbone.

I have *no control over the structure* of the api (it is the REST api from the wordpress plugin - woocommerce).

I have relatively little experience with Backbone and every json api, which I have always created myself has had the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@example.com",
        "order_number": "#3473388"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "email": "jane@example.com",
        "order_number": "#8877632"
    }
]
```

An array of objects, nice and simple!

*However,* the structure of the api I am working with now has the following stucture:

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "id": 130259,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john@example.com",
            "order_number": "#3473388"
        },
        {
            "id": 130259,
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "email": "jane@example.com",
            "order_number": "#3473388"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my model for an order:

```
App.Models.Order = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        order_number: ''
    }

});
```

And this is my collection of orders:

```
App.Collections.Orders = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: App.Models.Order,

    url: 'http://api.example.com/orders'

});
```

The structure of my model/collection does not map well with the api, and when `fetching` my collection, the data is returned, but doesn't fit. How do I work with backbone to accomadate this json structure?

## UPDATE

Overriding the parse method on the collection (thanks to Yura) like so returns the data:

```
App.Collections.Orders = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: App.Models.Order,

    url: 'http://api.example.com/orders',

    parse: function( resp ){
        return resp.orders;
    }

});
```

The data returned is multidimensional like so:

```
[
    {
        "id": 130285,
        "order_number": "#130285",
        "billing_address": {
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "company": "",
            "address_1": "13 Green Willow",
            "address_2": "",
            "city": "Celbridge",
            "state": "Kildare",
            "postcode": "",
            "country": "IE",
            "email": "johndoe@hotmail.com",
            "phone": "87384348043"
        }
    }
]
```

In the parse method, how do I map multidimensional json to my collection's models?

Comment: You need to override the `parse` method of your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your API returns an array of objects that can be used to initialize models, you can use `parse` on your collection, like so:

```
App.Collections.Orders = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: App.Models.Order,

    url: 'http://api.example.com/orders',

    parse: function( resp ){
        return resp.orders;
    }

});
```

If your API returned plain array of objects, you wouldn't need `parse`.
Documentation for Collection.parse: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

## Update

If you need to parse individual objects to model keys, you can add `parse` method on your model and return the object where keys will be the keys of your models and values passed from your response.

I have created a jsfiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/yuraji/x62jje39/

Comment: Thanks Yura. That worked for me. The data I'm getting back is multidimensional json. How could I map my collection's models to this result? I've updated my question to explain better.

Comment: You can map your json data to model keys right there in the `parse` method, that's basically what it's for. You prepare the object where keys are named according to model keys and `return` it. Note however, that now you will want to create `parse` method on your model, which will process individual objects into the model data.